# Как сделать, чтобы каждый раз было новое значение при сортировке?

Tags: javascript

сейчас иногда может повторятся

```js
array.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
```

Comment: Math.random() генерит случайное число и оно действительно может повториться, только вот в комбинации с sort это работает немного не так, положительные числа выводят значение на верх, отрицательные вниз. У вас в коде 3 варианта - > 0, 0, < 0. т.е каждая третья итерация примерно будет повторяться

Comment: ну вот. А можно избегать повторений?

Answer (score 1):

> Для организации сортировки массива в случайном порядке, нам необходимо присвоить каждому элементу массива случайное значение при помощи функции **Math.random()** и сортировку производить по полученному случайному значению.

*Предлагаю следующий метод*: Создаем функцию, в которую передаем массив, который требуется отсортировать в случайном порядке. 
В функции создаем новый массив объектов методом **.map()**, в котором будет храниться индекс элемента и случайное значение, полученное при помощи **функции Math.random()**.
Полученный массив сортируем по случайным значениям.
Собираем массив, куда в качестве элемента подставляем элемент исходного массива с соответствующим индексом из отсортированного и возвращаем результат

```js
const array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

function sortRnd(a,b) {
    return a.sortPos - b.sortPos;
}

function randomSort(inArr) {
    return inArr.map((item, id) => {
        return {
            id: id,
            sortPos: Math.random()
        }
    })
    .sort(sortRnd)
    .map(i => inArr[i.id]);
}

console.log(randomSort(array));
console.log(randomSort(array));
console.log(randomSort(array));
console.log(randomSort(array));
console.log(randomSort(array));
```